# Im getting undefined values in my nested objects

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

So i have 3 entity in my server side.

Main Entity (Student)

DBREF (Education and Parents)

```
@Id
private @Getter @Setter String id;
// fields
@Column(nullable=false)
@DBRef
private @Getter @Setter Education education;
```

Then when i try to bind my entity in the server side, i use state to define the entity's object, so this is how i initialize my state (depends on my entity).

```
 const [student, setStudent] = useState({
        // student properties
        education: {
            educationLevel: "",
           // education properties
        },
        parents: {
            // parents properties
        }
    })
```

Then after that i destruct the properties.

I already binded all the properties in my form, then when i check the it using react dev tools, the values of education and parents are undefined.

[image]

While the student properties is working fine. So every time i hit the submit button it returns (200), then when i check the values for parents and education in my mongoDB, all the properties is empty.